# Комментарии с noinspection вместо аннотаций @SuppressLint

Tags: java, android, аннотации

Случайно обнаружил странную функциональность.
Если в простом комментарии использовать конструкцию:

```
// noinspection <key>
```

то это работает на подобие аннотаций `@SuppressLint("<key>")`.
Ничего про это не нашел в документации. Пример использования:

```
// noinspection all
int i = 1 / 0;
```

Что известно об этой недокументированной функциональности?

Comment: Это аннотация IntelliJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это частная фича JetBrains реализованная Intellij/Android Studio/PHPStorm

Под ванильной Java это конечно же не работает - компилятор выдаст ошибку.

[Документация здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html)